# How to Check/Uncheck the checkboxes in the wxGrid from code?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a checkbox-column in the wxGrid column. I want to check/uncheck the chechboxes in the wxGrid from the code. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The function to set the state of a checkbox is wxCheckBox::SetValue(); If you have an array of checkboxes the code to set them true  is:

```
for(int i=0; i!=number_of_checkboxes; i++) {
checkbox_array[i]->SetValue(true);
}
```

to set value of first checkbox to false

```
checkbox_array[0]->SetValue(false);
```

this assuming you're using a pointer. if you aren't is:

```
checkbox_array[0].SetValue(false);
```

Comment: This is inapplicable here as there is no `wxCheckBox` to call this method on.

Answer (score 0):

`wxGrid` is a view on the data represented by `wxGridTable`, so to change the values shown in it you simply need to change the values of the cells in the table. The exact way to do it depends on the table you use, but with `wxGridStringTable` it's simply the matter of calling its `SetValue()` method.